# Is justifyContent: 'space-evenly' supported in RN 0.60.5?

Tags: react-native, justify

Environment:
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.5",

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs it appears to be supported: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props#justifycontent

Supported types include:

`enum('flex-start', 'flex-end', 'center', 'space-between', 'space-around', 'space-evenly')`

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it appears to work. But it don't. :/

Comment: Can you edit your question above and provide some more details with your code?

Answer (score 0):

`justifyContent: 'space-evenly'` is supported since RN 0.52.0, so it is supported in 0.60.5 too.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it appears to work. But it don't. :/